# Java string split method evaluation

Tags: java

I need to parse an input string for an application and have a question related to how java evaluates the result of the string **split()** method.

For example, in the code bellow:

```
} else if (arg.equals("-multiplePaths")) {
    // Check if we have multiple paths 
    if (args[count++].contains(":")) {
    for(String tmpIDLPath : args[count-1].split(":"))
        m_includePaths.add(tmpIDLPath);
    } else {
        // Only one
        m_includePaths.add(args[count-1]);
    }
```

how is for loop evaluated? Is the split operation computed once for each iteration or once at the beginning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array you are looping over is computes once per loop.

BTW Your check is redundant.

```
} else if (arg.equals("-multiplePaths")) {
    for(String tmpIDLPath : args[count-1].split(":"))
        m_includePaths.add(tmpIDLPath);
```

or

```
} else if (arg.equals("-multiplePaths")) {
    Collections.addAll(m_includePaths, args[count-1].split(":"));
```

Comment: Why is the check redundant? If the string does not contain ":" is the path still being added or not?

Comment: @Sebi if `split` can't find something to "split on", then it returns an array with only one element (the whole string where `split` was called on), so yes, it will work.

Comment: @Sebi it's redundant because you don't need it.  This code will do the same thing.